# How to detect "bad inputs" when designing a classifier?

Tags: classification

For example, warning casual drawings when recognizing hand-written digits.

Some quick thoughts:

- A bad input may be an outlier for the training data
- A bad input may cause noticeable ties across different labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more or less a separate classification problem, whether or not an image contains some hand-written text or not, so the simplest way to go would be to take your training data, add some negative examples and train on that.

It might be possible, as you suggest, to assume that the images of hand-written text form a compact cluster in the feature space, but it's not trivial since that would require a different set of features than the actual classification. Those features useful in classifying the images of hand-written text are often of little use in discriminating between such images and, e.g. portrait photos, and vice versa.

Comment: Any suggestions about the features? I think topological features may help.

Comment: @ziyuang I'd start with simple global features, like brightness histogram and dominant colors. It's hard to find a representative set of negative samples in such problems, so one should be especially careful not to overfit.